# linear equation with terms in denominator

Tags: systems-of-equations

Solve the equations:
$$\begin{cases}
3x  &-  &4y &+ &1/yx &= &12\\
4z  &-  &12x &+ &1/xz &= &3\\
12y &- &3z  &+ &1/yz &= &4\\
\end{cases}$$

By observation $x=1/3$, $y=1/4$, $z= 1$ is a solution. How to approach this question? I tried by multiplying third equation with second and substracting from first to make perfect squares but it's not getting solved.

Comment: Surely you've been here long enough to format your question in MathJax.

Comment: @DietrichBurde : Looks like I introduced extra '7' characters, my bad

Comment: have corrected the question and am sorry for typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking resultants we see that all solutions are given by
$$
(x,y,z)=(1/3,1/4,1), (-1/3,-1/4,-1)
$$
and
$$
y=( - 456976000x^5 + 1116535680x^4 - 2394256124x^3 - 1163624319x^2 - 556971724x
+ 138127536)/23037439,
$$

$$
z=( - 114244000x^5 + 253276920x^4 - 535731521x^3 - 452777364x^2 - 177971056x +
10655316)/26578395,
$$

where $x$ is a root of the polynomial

$$
676000x^6 - 1642680x^5 + 3555929x^4 + 1825200x^3 + 870688x^2 -
182520x + 23409=0.
$$
Since this polynomial has only non-real roots, the only real solutions are the ones given above.

Comment: the observation was pure luck... can we reach it logically??

Comment: Yes, use resultants!

Comment: how? resultants?

Comment: See [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).